# Coining a gramatically right word for a newly devised method

Tags: neologisms

I am writing a research paper in which a new method is devised.
In this method a mathematical function is rebuilt by combining some conical functions (apexes).

Is it grammatically right to name it *The Apex Combination Method*?

Or should it be *The Apexes Combination Method*?

Or maybe *Combination of Apexes*, which I don't like very much?

Comment: Another advantage of using the singular *apex*, you don't have to decide whether to use [apexes or apices](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apex) for the plural.

Comment: I normally use ***corpuses***, not ***corpora***, which according to [NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=corpuses%2Ccorpora&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccorpuses%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccorpora%3B%2Cc0) puts me rather seriously out on a limb. By comparison, using ***apexes*** instead of ***apices*** (which I *wouldn't* normally do) is actually [relatively common.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=apexes%2Capices&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Capexes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Capices%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the mathematical concept, but the singular *apex* sounds right to me. You wouldn't refer to a *computers network* or a *shoes store*.

You might also consider the continuous present tense, *Combining apexes*.